# Conditional probability with missing information

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have the following set of events:

$$X= \{x_0=A,x_1=A,x_2=A,x_3=A,x_4=A\}$$

and I want to calculate the probability

$$p(x_{i+1}=A|x_i=A)$$

I think that it should be $p(x_{i+1}=A|x_i=A) = 1$ as every time I have A in $x_i$ I also have $A$ in $x_{i+1}$. However, some of my colleges say that as I know that $x_4=A$, but I do not have information about the value of $x_5$ (it could be $A$ or not), then the probability should be $p(x_{i+1} = A | x_i = A) = 4/5$. To me that would be the same as saying that $x_5=B$, which we do not know.

In other words, suppose that I want to obtain
$$p(x_{i+1}=\bar{A} | x_i=A)$$

following this last method this would be $p(x_{i+1}=\bar{A}|x_i=A)$=1/5. But if all I have ever seen is $x_i=A$, why can I say that $x_{i+1}$ might not be $A$?

---

Some more information: I have a system that outputs a signal $x_i$ at each time step $i$, where $x_{i+1}$ is not independent from $x_{i}$, and $x_i$ can take any value ($A,B,C,D...$). The length of the signal is arbitrarily long (but finite), say $N$, and I analyze a subsample of length $w\ll N$. Given the subsample
$$X_w = \{A,A,A,A,A\}$$

what's the value of $p(x_{i+1}=A|x_i=A)$ in this particular window? Note that for the calculation I can only use the information contained in the subsample.

Comment: Think about it this way, let A represent the event that it is raining that day. If we see rain on day 0, day 1, day 2, day 3, and day 4, this still doesn't give us the information to say that the probability it will rain on day 5 is 1.

Comment: It all depends on your assumptions about the process $x$. The question is completely nonsensical without the assumptions.

Comment: @Green If all I have ever seen is rain, I can't say that on day 5 it is not going to rain. Of course, probably I don't have enough information, but as long as I know it is going to rain. Imagine that you go to a new planet, you have been there 4 days and it rained on all of them. Based on your observations it always rains on than planet.

Comment: @SlugPue I've added more information.

Comment: It's still impossible tell. You have to make assumptions about **how** the process depends on the past.